# Microsoft Dynamics CRM integration SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, crm

Have any of you done a MS CRM 4.0 and SharePoint integration. Any Pointers? I am new to both the CRM and SharePoint.

After a little more research, Id like to refine my question. I basically want to use IFRAME to add a SharePoint tab that will show the SharePoint page that I have created. Any hints on how to do that?

Also how would I get access to the CRM data fields in SharePoint. i.e. if I add a file in SharePoint, I want it to have all the metadata from the CRM property page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CRM <-> SharePoint integration is very common.  The MS CRM blog is a good place to start for pointers:

[MS CRM Blog post tagged with SharePoint](http://blogs.msdn.com/crm/archive/tags/SharePoint/default.aspx)

Also, the Dynamics CRM Virtual PC demo image has some SharePoint integration in it, where it shows pages from SharePoint in CRM.  You can download the VPC from here:

[Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 Virtual Machine](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=dd939ed9-87a5-4c13-b212-a922cc02b469&displaylang=en)

Once you have the VPC started, as I recall there is SharePoint integration on the Account entity - have a look in the onload event of the Account form in Customizations.

Comment: Thank You Gentlemen. This is really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your question in how to utilize IFrame to display custom .ASPX solution, you can refer to these posts :

[Microsoft Dynamics CRM IFRAME Magic](http://blogs.msdn.com/crm/archive/2009/04/15/microsoft-dynamics-crm-iframe-magic.aspx)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank You Hadi. I had found this link but was still not sure of how to integrate.